# Disable button if not match a record

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have here a script for matching records through ajax. What I need to do is if record match in database record don't disable the button. But my problem here was the save button was permanent disabled. What is the problem with my script? Any help will appreciate.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="item" id="item" value="" class="inputs" autocomplete="off">
<div><span id="status" class="inputs"></span></div>
<input type="button" name="sub" id="save">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('input[id="item"]').change(function()
{
var item = $("#item").val();
var msgbox = $("#status");
$('#save').prop('disabled',true);
//$("#status").html('<img src="loader.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Checking availability...');

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "check_ajax.php",
    data: "item="+item,
    success: function(msg){
    console.log(msg)
   $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request){
    if(msg == 'FOUND')
    {
    msgbox.html('<img src="images/available.png" align="absmiddle">');
    $("#save").prop("disabled",false);
    }
    else
    {
    $("#save").prop("disabled",true);
    msgbox.html(msg);
    }
   });
   }
  });// ajax close
return false;
});// change close
});// jquery close
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `ajax success callback` like,

```
success: function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
    if(msg == 'FOUND')
    {
       msgbox.html('<img src="images/available.png" align="absmiddle">');
       $("#save").prop("disabled",false);
    }
    else
    {
       $("#save").prop("disabled",true);
       msgbox.html(msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use attr method instead of prop. Then it will work fine.

```
$("#save").attr("disabled",false);
$("#save").attr("disabled",true);
```

And you are missing semicolon in success at console.log();

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(msg)
{
    console.log(msg);
    if(msg == 'FOUND')
    {
        msgbox.html('<img src="images/available.png" align="absmiddle">');

        $("#save").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#save").attr("disabled","disabled");
        msgbox.html(msg);
    }
};
```